# ggplot2: specify shape for density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In order to improve the visibility of my density plot if printed in black and white I would like to add markers to it:

```
foo <- data.frame(
  v2=sample(c(1,2,3),size=10,rep=T),
  v3=as.factor(sample(2,10,rep=T))
)

p <- ggplot(foo, aes(x=foo$v2, colour=foo$v3, shape=foo$v3))
p <- p + geom_line(stat="density")
p
```

I understand that the density curve is a continuous line, but it would be nice to put markers on it at given points. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Where do you want to add markers?

Comment: @jazurro: Either to tell to put `N` equally spaced markers, or to provide a vector with the `x` coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for that. Could I clarify one more thing? By saying marker, do you mean you want to add points in the graphic?

Comment: @jazurro: I would like to have circles, boxes on the line. In ggplot2 it is set with the `shape` keyword. I actually included it in my code above, but of course int this way it has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it then:

```
p <- ggplot(foo, aes(x=v2))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(linetype=v3,colour=v3),stat="density",size=2)
p
```

[image]

Now the difference should be clear.

Comment: @beginneR Thanks. I just copy-pasted the code as the OP posted. Thanks for correcting it.

Comment: Thank you, but this solution does not solve my problem: to easy distinguish lines in black and white I need different markers for different lines.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying a little the answer from @LyzandeR maybe you could achieve something similar to what you are asking for by using the `group` parameter:

```
p <- ggplot(foo, aes(x = v2, colour = v3, group = v3))
p <- p + 
    geom_line(stat='density', aes(linetype = v3), size = 3) +
    geom_line(stat='density', size = 1) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dashed", "dotted"))    
p
```

[image]

You can explore the different linetypes [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/), for example.